# How to send data to another activity and position of row when a button is clicked inside listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and I am using custom views for rows and in each row there is a button. I want that when this button was clicked some data is send to another activity. Consider the code below because it will give me exceptions and I tried another method of setTag and getTag and that will cause class cast exception while scrolling. The below code give me exception that frame layout can not be cast into `ListView` so how I correct this ?

```
    public class EngNewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private List<EnglishNews> mENList;
    private int mResource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public EngNewsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<EnglishNews> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);

            mResource = resource;
            mENList = objects;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if(convertView == null){

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, null);

                holder.mENDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pub_date);
                holder.mENTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eng_news_title);
                holder.mENSummary = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eng_news_summary);
                holder.mENImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eng_news_image);
                holder.mENDescBtn = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.read_more_eng_btn);
                holder.shareButton = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eng_fb_share_button);

                holder.mENTitle.setTypeface(headingStyle);
                holder.mENSummary.setTypeface(contentStyle);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            //associating the data position to the button through intent to give the desc activity
            holder.mENDescBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    View parentRow = (View) view.getParent();
                    ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
                    int pos = (Integer) listView.getPositionForView(parentRow);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(EnglishNewsActivity.this, EnglishNewsDescriptionActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("image_url", mENList.get(pos).getNewsImage());
                    intent.putExtra("title", mENList.get(pos).getNewsTitle());
                    intent.putExtra("date", mENList.get(pos).getNewsDate());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            holder.mENTitle.setText(mENList.get(position).getNewsTitle());
            });

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

My row Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:id="@+id/read_more_eng_btn"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eng_news_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/eng_fb_share_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eng_news_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pub_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eng_news_summary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="69dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share your full adapter code

Comment: I have edited the question with my adapter code

Comment: Your row layout please

Comment: There are multiple question like the one you asked. Try to search the web first before posting a question. Here you can see how to send data between activities. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android

Comment: holder.mENDescBtn = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.read_more_eng_btn);
              what is this . Shoulbn't this be a button ?

Comment: Why don't you use `position` value of `getView` method instead of picking position from list view by show many process? Just make your `position` parameter as `final` so that you can access it inside your `onClick` method.

Comment: I have saw all post and my code gives me exceptions I am just tried alot and now i am trying to ask that what is causing my code to give exceptions because I could not find it . So please do not down vote

Comment: Md Sufi Khan I do not know about what you have said and I tried and it worked thanks :)

Comment: I posted my answer below. If it helps you will you accept the answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView listView = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
```

I think this is where cast exception occures. 
I encourage to use of [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

```
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(NewsActivity.this, DescriptionActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("news_summary", mENList.get(i).getNewsSummary());
                intent.putExtra("news_url", mENList.get(i).getNewsUrl());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

set this in your NewsActivity.

**UPDATE**

I think the better way it to implement [BaseAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) instead of creating a custom ArrayAdapter.

```
public class EngNewsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<EnglishNews> mENList;
    private int mResource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private Context context;

    public EngNewsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<EnglishNews> objects) {
        this.context = context;
        mResource = resource;
        mENList = objects;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, null);

            holder.mENDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pub_date);
            holder.mENTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eng_news_title);
            holder.mENSummary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eng_news_summary);
            holder.mENImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eng_news_image);
            holder.mENDescBtn = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.read_more_eng_btn);
            holder.shareButton = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eng_fb_share_button);

            holder.mENTitle.setTypeface(headingStyle);
            holder.mENSummary.setTypeface(contentStyle);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //associating the data position to the button through intent to give the desc activity
        holder.mENDescBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EnglishNewsDescriptionActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image_url", mENList.get(position).getNewsImage());
                intent.putExtra("title", mENList.get(position).getNewsTitle());
                intent.putExtra("date", mENList.get(position).getNewsDate());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mENList != null && !mENList.isEmpty() ? mENList.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mENList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: "button is clicked inside listview"  he is asking inside button click and you are doing listview click. wrong answer.

Comment: Yes you get me wrong please read the question carefully before you answer

Answer (score 0):

//Add context

```
private Context context;

public EngNewsAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<EnglishNews> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        //context use
        this.context=context;

    }
```

//click

```
holder.mENDescBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EnglishNewsDescriptionActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image_url", mENList.get(position).getNewsImage());
                intent.putExtra("title", mENList.get(position).getNewsTitle());
                intent.putExtra("date", mENList.get(position).getNewsDate());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You need to set `position` as final. Otherwise line `intent.putExtra("image_url", mENList.get(position).getNewsImage());` will give you compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like below:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ....

        //associating the data position to the button through intent to give the desc activity
        holder.mENDescBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EnglishNewsDescriptionActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image_url", mENList.get(position).getNewsImage());
                intent.putExtra("title", mENList.get(position).getNewsTitle());
                intent.putExtra("date", mENList.get(position).getNewsDate());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ......
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: you need context for Intent call 
 Intent intent = new Intent(EnglishNewsActivity.this, EnglishNewsDescriptionActivity.class); //line not working in adapter